# Optimizing for the longest distance travelled

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I was had a question about optimizing for the longest distance travelled.

Suppose there is a highway which we can use to travel for a specific distance based on a set of fee rules involving 3 types of tokens `x, y, z`.
You are given a set amount of each type of tokens and The fee rules are of the following form and is asked to maximize the distance travelled,

```
 30x's + 10y's + 10z's -> d_1km
 30x's + 10y's + 0z's  -> d_2km
 30x's + 0y's + 0z's   -> d_3km
 5x's + 0y's + 0z's    -> d_4km
 5x's + 3y's + 3z's    -> d_5km
```

My initial thought was to order the distance travelled from largest to smallest and try to spend my tokens in that order, but I believe this will cause me to miss out on some edge deals that will enable me to go even further. I believe I've seen some mathematical concept to optmizing this type of problems, but I can't remember exactly what this is called. Any hints or pointers as to how to tackle this problem is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The broad topic is known as [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (ILP), and the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) is one approach to solving ILP problems.

Comment: A greedy approach is to analyze the deals in order of efficiency. In the example, `d_4km` is the best deal because it uses 5x's to go 4km. `d_1km`, `d_2km`, and `d_3km` would never be chosen because they have much worse efficiency, using 30x's to go less than 4km. So the only real choices are `d_4km` and `d_5km`, and the answer is to use `d_5km` until you run out of one type of token, and then use `d_4km` while there are enough `x` tokens left.

Comment: @user3386109 simplex algorithm is not usable for ILP, only LP.

Comment: @AirSquid [The use of simplex in ILP is discussed in the article that I linked.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Algorithms). For this problem, given that no negative numbers are involved, you can certainly solve with simplex, and then round down. That should give an answer that's as good as a greedy algorithm, and the answer could then be refined using hill climbing.

Comment: @user3386109 That's a **terrible idea.**  Direct quote from the article you linked:  "The naive way to solve an ILP is to simply remove the constraint that x is integer, solve the corresponding LP (called the LP relaxation of the ILP), and then round the entries of the solution to the LP relaxation. But, not only may this solution not be optimal, it may not even be feasible; that is, it may violate some constraint."  Just use the proper algorithm (or solver that employs it), such as branch & bound

Comment: The note about violating some constraint only applies when negative numbers or subtraction are involved. That doesn't apply to OP's question.

Comment: You're taking my comment out of context. There are no non-integer values in OP's question.

Comment: @user3386109.  That's true, but there are many non-integer relationships, which are equally problematic if you try to employ real valued solutions.  The distance on the first highway relative to the `x` tokens spent is `d1/30`.  There are correct algorithms for this, why not just use the right tool for the job?

Comment: @AirSquid You've got two things going on in your comment. I'm interested in the first part of the comment up to `d1/30`. Are you trying to say that simplex will not be able to find a real-valued solution to the OP's problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248183/discussion-between-airsquid-and-user3386109).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a dynamic programming approach here as well, but a standard way to approach this type of problem is to set it up as an Integer Linear Program (ILP) as the decision variables are naturally integers.  There are several python packages that can set up the model (`pulp`, `pyomo`, `CVXOPT`, others), and several free solvers that can solve ILP problems such as `CBC` and `glpk` using the "branch and bound" or similar algorithm.  Most frameworks that can set up the model are separate from the solver.

Here is an example setup of your problem in `pyomo` which uses the separately installed `cbc` solver.

#### Code

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# DATA
#                  dist  X   Y   Z
highways = { 'h1': (24, (30, 10, 10)),
             'h2': (17, (30, 10, 0 )),
             'h3': (22, (30, 0,  0 )),
             'h4': (8,  (5,  0,  0 )),
             'h5': (13, (5,  3,  3 ))}

tokens = {'X': 64, 'Y': 15, 'Z': 12}

# a convenience...
token_types = list('XYZ')
costs = {}
for idx, t in enumerate(token_types):
    for h in highways.keys():
        costs[(h, t)] = highways[h][1][idx]

# set up ILP
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# SETS

m.H = pyo.Set(initialize=highways.keys())
m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=token_types)      # token types

# PARAMS
m.tokens_avail = pyo.Param(m.T, initialize=tokens)
m.dist         = pyo.Param(m.H, initialize={k:v[0] for k, v in highways.items()})
m.cost         = pyo.Param(m.H, m.T, initialize=costs)

# VARS
m.pay    = pyo.Var(m.H, m.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)   # pay this many tokens of type t on highway h
m.travel = pyo.Var(m.H, domain=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)        # travel on highway h this many times

# OBJECTIVE
# maximize distance traveled, add some tiny penalty to prevent spending unneeded tokens
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.sum_product(m.dist, m.travel) - 0.01 * pyo.sum_product(m.pay), sense=pyo.maximize)

# CONSTRAINTS
# limit token use to available, for each type
def token_limit(m, t):
    return sum(m.pay[h, t] for h in highways) <= m.tokens_avail[t]
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=token_limit)

# pay the cost of each trip
def pay_tokens(m, h, t):
    if not m.cost[h, t]:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    return m.travel[h] <= m.pay[h, t] / m.cost[h, t]
m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(m.H, m.T, rule=pay_tokens)

# check the model...
m.pprint()


solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
res = solver.solve(m)
print(res)

tot_distance = pyo.sum_product(m.dist, m.travel)

print(f'total distance achieved: {pyo.value(tot_distance)}')

for idx in m.travel.index_set():
    if m.travel[idx]:
        print(f'travel {idx} {pyo.value(m.travel[idx])} times')

for idx in m.pay.index_set():
    if m.pay[idx]:
        print(f'pay {pyo.value(m.pay[idx])} {idx[1]} tokens on {idx[0]}')
```

#### Output (partial)

```
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: -115.16
  Upper bound: -115.16
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 13
  Number of variables: 20
  Number of binary variables: 0
  Number of integer variables: 20
  Number of nonzeros: 20
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.01
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 2
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.01609015464782715
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

total distance achieved: 116.0
travel h4 8.0 times
travel h5 4.0 times
pay 40.0 X tokens on h4
pay 20.0 X tokens on h5
pay 12.0 Y tokens on h5
pay 12.0 Z tokens on h5
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the code! I really appreciate it. I do have a follow up question. Do you reckon it would be possible to do a case analysis and create new additional rules based on the existing rules, then add them to the set of rules, then go down the set of rules according to the priority? I hope this makes sense. (I don't think this would work because there can be infinitely many new rules I can add for any given system)

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your secondary question.  Constraints (aka rules) are arbitrary, so you can always add more.  If you want to do comparisons/what-if analysis, you can always either:  turn individual constraints on/off and re-solve, or put in clever penalties/bonuses and change weightings to see an array of results by re-solving with different bonuses.  For instance, in your toy example, you could "cost" x-tokens at $1, $2, $5, $9 in individual cases, solve and look at costs...  "priorities" are usually handled by differing weights and some score in the objective.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. I am very new to this whole linear programming area, but this is a great introduction and I appreciate it. I think for my specific problem (diff fare rules than in question) I managed to be able to do a case analysis for individual fares and came up w a deterministic set steps instead of applying the proper linear programming.

Comment: ok, great.  Just be careful with the deterministic steps...  One other bonus of using LP/ILP tools is that you get an optimality **guarantee** with the solution.  If the problem is small, you might exhaustively build all combos or such.  You can always plug data into my code and check or if you don't have tools installed, edit you post and include actual data/new rules and I can re-run.  There are many good intro texts and tutorials out there.  Good hunting!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the simplex algorithm, typically used to solve such operation research problems: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

You can implement such an algorithm on your own but there are several "solver" libraries that already implement this algorithm.

Comment: The problem is integer based.  Simplex method is only for continuous value LP problems.